# Tescafe -q not working properly (quarantine mode)

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcafe, e2e, flakyness

so I have some flakiness in my e2e tests and want to use testcafe's quarantine mode to minimize pipeline failures. For some reason the tests wont rerun after failing.

```
testcafe 'chrome:headless --no-sandbox --autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required' --skip-js-errors --skip-uncaught-errors -q attemptLimit=5,successThreshold=1
```

thanks in advance

EDIT: I found out that it works, if I add the quarantine-mode key to the testcafe config file. CLI wise its just getting ignored somehow.

Comment: Make sure that you are using TestCafe version 1.15.0, where these options appeared.

Comment: I did that and can confirm that I'm using "dependencies": {"testcafe": "^1.15.0"}

Comment: We will be happy to help you and diagnose this problem. However, I was unable to reproduce it.
Please submit a bug report here [https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md) and add your environment information as well as a sample project and tests.